# Is it possible for collections to get fragmented?

Tags: c#, collections, fragmentation

Consider registering entrance of new members in a `Dictionary` and the time of entrance:

```
Dictionary<string, DateTime> members = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
members.Add("Bob", DateTimeNow);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
members.Add("Joe", DateTimeNow);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
members.Add("Susan", DateTimeNow);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
// Now Joe exits
members.Remove("Joe");
// Then Mike enters
members.Add("Mike", DateTimeNow);
```

Now the question is where's `Mike` location in `Dictionary`. Is he added to the end of `Dictionary` or he will fill the empty location of `Susan` (if we iterate with `foreach` or access the `Dictionary` via index)? Is the behavior guaranteed for all of the times?

Comment: Why do you need to know this? Even if it may be that way, that is an implementation detail that you should not rely on!

Comment: "Is the behavior guaranteed for all of the times?" - No.

Comment: If the orders are guaranteed, then I can assume the first item is the earliest entrance and the last item is the latest entrance, so I don't need iterate and sort items.

Comment: To save storage, slots will be reused at least some of the time, so you can't rely on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Dictionary is not ordered, so you can't do any reasoning as to the order they're returned in if you iterate over the keys.

As the MSDN site tells us, Dictionary is implemented as a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), and:

> The order in which the items are
>   returned is undefined.

You should use a [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) if you want to iterate over the keys in a defined order.

Answer (score 1):

The notion of order is not defined for hashtable which what Dictionary represents. You can never rely on items being in a particular order. This behavior is not guaranteed. A Dictionary is used to quickly access a given item by key.

Quote from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> For purposes of enumeration, each item
>   in the dictionary is treated as a
>   `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` structure
>   representing a value and its key. The
>   order in which the items are returned
>   is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a `Dictionary` is done via `key` and not via `index` - so the question it self is meaning less.
As all answers already stated - a `Dictionary` has no order, and is implemented via a `Hashtable` ([Wiki Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) - Take the time to read it)

The `Dictionary` it self can ***expand*** and ***compress*** depending on the volume of data it maintains and its own implementation, but when using a rich framework like `.NET` your don't need to bother with that question, it is done for you. You can read the `Dynamic Resizing` section in the WIKI page to learn on the implementation if it interests you.